# Function pointers initialized by lambda and their scope

Tags: c++, c++17

I have written the following code, which shall do element-wise transformation on arrays of the type `x=a op b`. `T` is numeric type (float, double, int, uint8_t, uint32_t, ...)

```
template <typename T>
void processFrame(Args ARG, T* a_array, T* b_array, T* x_array, uint32_t elmcount) 
{

    if(ARG.multiply)
    {   
        std::transform(A_array, A_array + elmcount, B_array, x_array, std::multiplies());
    } else if(ARG.divide)
    {   
        std::transform(A_array, A_array + elmcount, B_array, x_array, std::divides());
    } else if(ARG.min)
    {   
        std::transform(A_array, A_array + elmcount, B_array, x_array, [](T i, T j) {return std::min(i, j);});
    }   
}
```

The problem with this code is that I need to repeat the `std::transform` line multiple times but only transform type really changes. After googling I ended up with using pointer to function populated by lambda.

```
template <typename T>
using Operator = T (*)(const T&, const T&);

template <typename T>
void processFrame(Args ARG, T* A_array, T* B_array, T* x_array, uint32_t elmcount)
{
    Operator<T> op = nullptr;

    if(ARG.multiply)
    {   
        op = [](const T &i, const T &j) { return T(i * j); };
    } else if(ARG.divide)
    {
        op = [](const T &i, const T &j) { return T(i / j); };
    } else if(ARG.inverseDivide)
    {
        op = [](const T &i, const T &j) { return T(j / i); };
    } else if(ARG.add)
    {
        op = [](const T &i, const T &j) { return T(i + j); };
    } else if(ARG.subtract)
    {
        op = [](const T &i, const T &j) { return T(i - j); };
    } else if(ARG.max)
    {
        op = [](const T &i, const T &j) { return std::max(i, j); };
    } else if(ARG.min)
    {
        op = [](const T &i, const T &j) { return std::min(i, j); };
    }
    std::transform(A_array, A_array + elmcount, B_array, x_array, op);
}
```

Now it is working but I am not sure if I don't use unallocated memory. As op is formally pointer and I initialize it by lambda         , shall not that lambda go out of scope at the end of each if block? Is my `std::transfrom` not using pointer to non existing object?

Comment: I think the idea is to not pass `ARG.divide` as a parameter, but `std::divides()` instead, so you don't need the whole function. Also, why pass raw pointers? That's not very C++ish. Perhaps this is a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you want to tell us why you want such a function in the first place.

Comment: To me `op = [](const T &i, const T &j) { return T(i * j); };` looks like you have implemented `op = std::multiplies<T>();`, just on your own.

Comment: @Thomas Weller That is possible but unfortunately I have found no  `std::divides()` equivalent for min and max so in this case I would have to use lambda function anyway. When my code is very C++ish, then it uses the concepts, which I don't understand fully and which produce errors that are for me hard to debug, so I like to stick with naked pointers.

Comment: Do some coding katas in C++ which use iterators. It may take a few hours, but once you're familiar with them, it's wonderful. No pointers, no element counting, ...

Comment: @Thomas Weller your solution produces error: assigning to 'Operator<unsigned short>' (aka 'unsigned short (*)(const unsigned short &, const unsigned short &)') from incompatible type 'std::multiplies<unsigned short>'
        op = std::multiplies<T>();
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ I can live with lambdas, there is no speed advantage.

Comment: As alternative, `auto do_transform = [&](auto op){ std::transform(A_array, A_array + elmcount, B_array, x_array, op); }` and `if(ARG.multiply) { do_transform(std::multiplies()); } else if (ARG.divide) { do_transform(std::divides()); } /*..*/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is safe.

Function pointers are valid throughout the length of the program (with exception of `dlopen` stuff...).

Lambdas without capture are implicitly convertible to function pointers through [magic](https://cppinsights.io/s/d5d0172d). Each lambda expression creates a distinct type and returns a new object of that type.

Yes, the object goes out of scope, but the type of course doesn't, neither does its static methods which will be the function stored inside the pointer.

Comment: "_its static methods_": The call operator is not `static` though, although of course that doesn't make much of a difference if there is no state to the lambda. The specification says something along the lines of "calling this function pointer behaves as if calling the call operator on a default-constructed instance" (at least since C++20),

Comment: @user17732522 I know it is not, I meant the generated static method from the link. But thanks for the clarification.